# Групировка по нескольким фильтрам

Tags: c#, массивы, .net, классы, linq

Есть вот такой класс

```
var workers = new[]
{
    new Worker {Name = "Иванов", Salary = 40000},
    new Worker {Name = "Петров", Salary = 3000},
    new Worker {Name = "Иванов", Salary = 5000},
    new Worker {Name = "Сидоров", Salary = 7844},
    new Worker {Name = "Котельников", Salary = 1415},
    new Worker {Name = "Иванов2", Salary = 32970},
 };
```

Необходимо сделать группировку по одинаковым элементам, вот так:

```
var model = workers.GroupBy(x=>x.Name).Select(x=>new Element{...})
```

Здесь я сгруппирую элементы по Name индивидуально, но мне надо добавить фильтр который будет группировать например: Иванов + Иванов2, для другого элемента Сидоров + Котельников.

Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Comment: Есть одна из перегрузок, которая позволяет указать функцию. Так вот в этой функции вы можете описать свою логику группировки.

Comment: Звучит как XY-проблема, по какому конкретному критерию ты хочешь группировать?

Comment: @yolosora мне нужно сгрупировать по Name, но при этом что бы некоторые разные указывались в 1 выбранный. Вроде все в топике описано

Comment: @Unnamed не описано. По какому критерию выбрана, например, пара "Сидоров + Котельников"?  Очевидно, их что-то должно объединять.

Comment: @yolosora ничего их не объединяет, это мое решение их объединить

Comment: @Unnamed тогда только вручную описывать метод группировки с захардкоженными строками. Хотя вся эта затея выглядит отвратительно.

Comment: @yolosora больше вариантов решения я не вижу, мне нужно именно это. Потому на выводе приходится перебором выводить каждую такую строчку по несколько раз, что не есть хорошо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать дополнительный словарь

```
var workers = new[]
{
    new Worker {Name = "Иванов", Salary = 40000},
    new Worker {Name = "Петров", Salary = 3000},
    new Worker {Name = "Иванов", Salary = 5000},
    new Worker {Name = "Сидоров", Salary = 7844},
    new Worker {Name = "Котельников", Salary = 1415},
    new Worker {Name = "Иванов2", Salary = 32970},
};

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    {"Иванов","Group 1"},
    {"Иванов2","Group 1"},
    {"Сидоров","Group 2"},
    {"Котельников","Group 2"},      
};

var model = workers
            .GroupBy(x => dict.ContainsKey(x.Name) ? dict[x.Name] : x.Name)
            .Dump();
```

На выходе:

[image: ...]

Comment: Конкретную проблему это конечно решает, но при изменении исходных данных и этих рандомых хотелок по группировке - постоянно нужно лезть и править код, сама по себе хотелка в такой формулировке - порочна :(

Comment: @yolosora в данной реализации, что у меня, ничего не меняется, все статично.